# Can I get custom date format for pluck(lists) on Laravel5?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

My DB records are this.

```
tests table
id date
1 2016-07-01
2 2016-07-31
3 2016-08-01
4 2016-08-15
5 2016-08-31
6 2016-09-01
```

I wanna choose record by month.
Now my code is this.

Controller

```
$months = \App\Test::where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                          ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                          ->pluck('date', 'date');
```

View

```
{{ Form::select('month', $months, old('month'), ['id' => 'month']) }}

( that generate this. )

<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value="2016-07-01">2016-07-01</option>
    <option value="2016-07-31">2016-07-31</option>
    <option value="2016-08-01">2016-08-01</option>
    <option value="2016-08-15">2016-08-15</option>
</select>
```

But I wanna this.

```
$months = \App\Test::where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                          ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                          // ->format('m').
                          ->pluck('date', 'date');

{{ Form::select('month', $months, old('month'), ['id' => 'month']) }}

( I wanna generate this )

<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

I wanna use format with pluck but cant do this sadly
Any solves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone, I had given up to pickup month from DB yesterday,
But Today!! I got TRUE Answer with this code XD.
NOTE, This code will work Postgresql only,
And where ... now() is too. this is postgres code.
Mysql or sqlite have to change DB raw and where code ya.

```
$months = \App\Test::select(\DB::raw('DATE_PART(\'MONTH\', date) AS MONTH'))
                        ->where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                        ->pluck('month', 'month');
```

Comment: What about duplicates? Do you really want a list  like (7,7,8,8,8,9)?

Comment: I think pluck('month','month') remove duplicate. At least my environment work so. If method is pluck('month'), Duplicate will so occur. If we need to remove duplicate expressly, I think add ->distinct() method before pluck.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that, through three ways.
All of those solutions depend on the fact that the date attribute is not a Carbon instance, which is your case.

1. An accessor for the date attribute to return the format your wish:

In your Test Model

#### Test.php

```php
public function getDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', $value)->format('m');
}
```

However this will affect the code everywhere.

2. The second way, is to create custom attribute.

```php
public function getFormattedDateAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', $this->date)->format('m');
}
```

3. The third way is to edit the collection itself.

```php
$months = \App\Test::where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                                      ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                                      ->pluck('date');
       
$months->each(function($month){
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', $month)->format('m');
        });
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, Every code is not work X(
First One, Brought me this fatal error Call to a member function format() on string.
Next One, That brought no messages but format is not changed.
Last One, Brought me Call to a member function format() on string.

Hell I made any mistakes?
To tell the truth, Column Name is open_at.
So I change function name getOpenAtAttribute($value) but comes same.

Comment: OK, I though the attribute is already a date one. I am updating my answer to cater for that.

Comment: check it now please

Comment: Same...(Off course I have Carbon and test that)
Should I change Controller or View if model create functions?
Or Need to change anything on model (like protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i'; )
Or ... add month column on DB? (I think that's bad way)

Comment: I'm decide to use {{ Form::selectMonth('month', old('month'), ['id' => 'month']) }} temporary. It's not so impotant to get month from DB on my site. Thanks to reply. I choose you best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$months = \App\Test::select(DB::raw('to_char(date, \'MM\')'))
                      ->where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                      ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                      ->pluck('date', 'date');
```

This will yield you a list of months.

More [info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: This is related to the DB engine, Laravel provides many ways to do it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pluck and take the Carbon date getter at the same time like this:

```
->pluck('date.month');
```

Source of getters https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters