# How to add strings to array key if that made by laravel5 pluck(lists) method?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, centos6

Yesterday I solved [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095477/can-i-get-custom-date-format-for-plucklists-on-laravel5), Thanks Everyone.

Next problem. Not so important but I feel concern, Look this code.

Controller

```
$months = \App\Test::select(\DB::raw('DATE_PART(\'MONTH\', date) AS MONTH'))
                    ->where('date', '<=', 'now()')
                    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                    ->pluck('month', 'month');
                    // this code generate like this.
                    // Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [8] => 8 [7] => 7 ) )
```

View

```
{{ Form::select('month', $months, old('month'), ['id' => 'month']) }}

( now generate this. )

<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

I hope to add string to key like this

```
<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value="8">8month</option>
    <option value="7">7month</option>
</select>
```

I think that can do with foreach like this.

```
$array = ["8" => "8", "7" => "7"];

print_r($array); // Array ( [8] => 8 [7] => 7 )

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key.'month'] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
}

print_r($array); // well done! Array ( [8month] => 8 [7month] => 7 )
```

So test it but...

```
print_r($months); // Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [8] => 8 [7] => 7 ) )

foreach($months as $key => $value){
    $array[$key.'month'] = $value;
    unset($months[$array]);
}

print_r($months); // Not Working WTF!! Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Any Solves?

Comment: Yes I know string doesn't need every key. That could solve just simply add strings to blade like this 

{{ Form::select('month', $months, old('month'), ['id' => 'month']) }}Month

But not so beautiful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that mistake is the answer lmao XD
truly work this, forgive my stupid.

```
foreach($months as $key => $value){
    $months[$key.'month'] = $value;
    unset($months[$key]);
}
```

P.S.

Above Code is **MISTAKE**

This Code is true.

```
foreach($months as $key => $value){
    $months[$value] = $value.'month';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$months` variable is `Collection` instance. You can use `$months->put($key, $value)` or `$months->push($value)`
Check out colllection methods [here](http://devdocs.io/laravel~5.2/api/5.2/illuminate/database/eloquent/collection)

Edit:

Also, I noticed you used wrong variable in second example. Shouldn't it be like this?

```
foreach($months as $key => $value){
    $months[$key.'month'] = $value;
    unset($months[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Oops Ya that's it. Just simply mistake. Not the cause of this issue thx.